# Qt cmake --build . error fatal error: winapifamily.h: No such file or directory #include <winapifamily.h>

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, ninja, qt6

I was building qt6 source, following this tutorial https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_6_from_Git

My file system

```
./C:
  ./Qt
     ./qt-src //the source folder
     ./qt-6   //the build folder
```

I have configured it with

> ..\qt6-src\configure.bat -prefix C:\Qt\qt6

but faced error while building it from

> cmake --build .

the error

```
compilation terminated.
[6/9076] Building CXX object qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/CMakeFiles/BundledHarfbuzz.dir/hb-dummy.cc.obj
FAILED: qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/CMakeFiles/BundledHarfbuzz.dir/hb-dummy.cc.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\c++.exe -DHAVE_ATEXIT -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DHAVE_OT -DHB_EXTERN="" -DHB_NDEBUG -DHB_NO_UNICODE_FUNCS -DHB_NO_WIN1256 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_JAVA_STYLE_ITERATORS -DQT_NO_NARROWING_CONVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DQT_NO_VERSION_TAGGING -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWINVER=0x0A00 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -D_UNICODE -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00 -IC:/Qt/qt-src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/include/harfbuzz -IC:/Qt/qt-6/qtbase/src/corelib/Core_autogen/include -IC:/Qt/qt-6/qtbase/include -IC:/Qt/qt-6/qtbase/include/QtCore -IC:/Qt/qt-src/qtbase/src/corelib -IC:/Qt/qt-6/qtbase/src/corelib -IC:/Qt/qt-6/qtbase/src/corelib/global -IC:/Qt/qt-6/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel -IC:/Qt/qt-src/qtbase/src/corelib/../3rdparty/tinycbor/src -IC:/Qt/qt-6/qtbase/include/QtCore/6.3.1 -IC:/Qt/qt-6/qtbase/include/QtCore/6.3.1/QtCore -IC:/Qt/qt-src/qtbase/src/corelib/../3rdparty/double-conversion/double-conversion -IC:/Qt/qt-src/qtbase/src/corelib/../3rdparty/double-conversion -IC:/Qt/qt-6/qtbase/src/corelib/.rcc -IC:/Qt/qt-src/qtbase/mkspecs/win32-g++ -IC:/Qt/qt-6/qtbase/include/QtZlib -IC:/Qt/qt-src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/zlib -IC:/Qt/qt-6/qtbase/src/3rdparty/zlib -IC:/Qt/qt-src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre2/src -IC:/Qt/qt-src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng -DNDEBUG -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -w -fno-exceptions -Wa,-mbig-obj -std=c++1z -MD -MT qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/CMakeFiles/BundledHarfbuzz.dir/hb-dummy.cc.obj -MF qtbase\src\3rdparty\harfbuzz-ng\CMakeFiles\BundledHarfbuzz.dir\hb-dummy.cc.obj.d -o qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/CMakeFiles/BundledHarfbuzz.dir/hb-dummy.cc.obj -c C:/Qt/qt-src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/hb-dummy.cc
In file included from C:/Qt/qt-src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/src/hb-common.cc:29:0,
                 from C:/Qt/qt-src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/hb-dummy.cc:7:
C:/Qt/qt-src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/src/hb.hh:208:26: fatal error: winapifamily.h: No such file or directory
 #include <winapifamily.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed
```

Comment: Just to be sure, are you in a visual studio prompt (64 bit)?

Comment: it's a administrator powershell in windows 10

Comment: You have to use the visual studio command prompt (64 bit) as per the README.

Comment: can you please provide a link to readme github repo?

Comment: I meant this: https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2022-July/042815.html

Comment: using visual studio 2019 cmd doesn't work

Comment: Please, do not just say does not work, but say what does not work, etc.